# How to copy a file box URL rooted in folder directory?

Tags: python, box

I need to create an script that helps me pick the URL from a Box file that has a path in my computer.
I've the Box desktop application installed.

Like: `C:\Users\Thiago.Oliveira\Box\`

I've created this script:

```py
# Providing the folder path
origin = r'C:\\Users\\Thiago.Oliveira\\Box\\XXXXXXX.xlsx'
target = f'C:\\Users\\Thiago.Oliveira\\Box\\XXXXXXX{datetime.date.today()}.xlsx'

# Fetching the list of all the files
shutil.copy(origin, target)
print("Files are copied successfully")
```

This helps me out to copy and rename the file for this box folder. But I also want to pick up the URL from the newly created file so I can send it over in an e-mail.

I haven't found anything that would help me with this.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, see the example below.
This example is using the [box python sdk](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk), and this is a JWT auth application script.

After uploading the file, the box sdk returns a file object, which has many properties.

I'm not sure what you mean by "pick up the URL", it could be the direct download URL of the file or a shared link.
The example is for the direct download URL.

To get the destination FOLDER_ID, you can look at the browser URL when you open the folder on the box.com app.
e.g.:[image of demo folder url in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW0cA.png)

```
from datetime import date
import os
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client


def main():
    auth = JWTAuth.from_settings_file(".jwt.config.json")
    auth.authenticate_instance()
    client = Client(auth)

    folder_id = "163422716106"

    user = client.user().get()
    print(f"User: {user.id}:{user.name}")

    folder = client.folder(folder_id).get()
    print(f"Folder: {folder.id}:{folder.name}")

    with open("./main.py", "rb") as file:
        basename = os.path.basename(file.name)
        file_name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(basename)[1]
        file_time = date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        box_file_name = file_name + "_" + file_time + file_ext
        print(f"Uploading {box_file_name} to {folder.name}")
        box_file = folder.upload_stream(file, box_file_name)
    box_file.get()

    print(f"File: {box_file.id}:{box_file.name}")
    print(f"Download URL: {box_file.get_download_url()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print("Done")
```

Resulting in:

```
User: 20344589936:UI-Elements-Sample
Folder: 163422716106:Box UI Elements Demo
Uploading main_20230203.py to Box UI Elements Demo
File: 1130939599686:main_20230203.py
Download URL: https://public.boxcloud.com/d/1/b1!5CgJ...fLc./download
```